# Non-scaffold GWT UiBinder in Spring Roo (SpringSource Tool Suite)

Tags: eclipse, spring, gwt, spring-roo, uibinder

In my autogenerated ~/src/main/ folder, I have a folder called 'frontend' with my Java UiBinder file and my .ui.xml UiBinder file. How do I make STS/Roo run this instead of ApplicationScaffold.html?

Furthermore, what am I supposed to do with ApplicationScaffold? It seems useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ApplicationScaffold.html file loads the ApplicationScaffold.nocache.js javascript file which bootstraps the GWT app. by calling the class which is mentioned in the ApplicationScaffold.gwt.xml file. Search for

I haven't tried this out myself but was just trying to figure out how to run the spring roo generated app in gwt debug mode inside eclipse and like this you can follow yourself whats happening (install the google gwt plugin) and right click on the roo project and do: properties->google->this project has a war file and point to the target/pizzashop-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT folder. Then run -> debug as -> Gwt application ...